# What are the canonical texts in Hindu Astrology (Jyotisha)?

Tags: astrology

Can someone make a list of the classical Hindu Astrological texts?

Answer (score 0):

This list is not exhaustive. However, it includes almost all the major classics.

1. Brihat Parasar Hora Sastra by Sage Parasara (the most important book)
2. Phaladeepika by Mantreshwara (arguably the second most important book)
3. Saravali by Kalyana Varma
4. Jataka Parijata by Vaidyanatha Dikshita
5. Jataka Bharnam by Dhundiraj​
6. Brihat Jataka by Varahamihira
7. Sarvarth Chintamani by Venkatesa Sarma
8. Garga Hora by Sage Gargacharya
9. Satyajatakam by Sage Satyacharya
10. Uttarakalamrita by Kalidasa
11. Sambhu Hora Prakasha by Punj Raja
12. Jatakalankara by Ganesa
13. Yavana Jataka by Yavanacharya Sphujidhwaja
14. Jataka Tatva by Mahadeva
15. Sanketa Nidhi by Ram Dayalu
16. Bhavarth Ratnakar by Ramanujacharya
17. Bhava Kutuhalam by Jeevnath Jha
18. Bhava Prakasha by Jeevnath Jha
19. Laghu Parasari (or Jataka Chandrika or Ududaya Pradip)
20. Madhya Parasari (or Ududaya Dasha)
21. Maansagari by Janardan
22. Hora Ratnam by Bala Bhadra
23. Chamatkar Chintamani by Bhattanarayan
24. Hora Sara by Prithuyasas (Son of Varahamihira)
25. Hora Makarand by Gunakar
26. Bhava Manjari by Mukund Daivajna
27. Laghu Jatakam by Varahamihira
28. Brihat Samhita by Varahamihira​
29. Jatakadesamarga by Somayaji​
30. Jyotisharnava Navanitam
31. Bhrigu Sutram by Sage Bhrigu
32. Sripatipaddhati by Sripati
33. Tajik Neelkanthi by Acharya Neelakantha
34. Daivajna Vallabha by Varahamihira
35. Prasna Marga by Narayanan Nambutiri​
36. Prasanagnana by Bhattopala
37. Pragnaana Deepika
38. Prasna Tantra by Neelakanta
39. Shatpanchasika by Prithuyasas (Son of Varahamihira)
40. Jaimini Sutras by Sage Jaimini​ (Jaimini school of Hindu Astrology is based on this book)
41. Jataka Sara Sangraha by Raghava Bhatta
42. Chandra Kala Nadi (or Deva Keralam) by Achyuta
43. Saptarishi Nadi (there are many Nadi books. I have included only a few)
44. Suka Nadi
45. Bhrigu Nadi
46. Dhruva Nadi
47. Nandi Nadi
48. Muhurta Chintamani by Daivagye Acharya Shriram
49. Kalaprakasika
50. KP Reader​s by K S Krishnamurti (this is a recent book written in twentieth century. This is also written in English. So technically it is not a classic. But, this book is the foundation for an entire branch of Hindu Astrology known as KP or Krishnamurty Paddhati. So I have included it in the list)

Comment: Who is mantreshwara mentioned in second point ? And was Kalidasa also an astrologer ?

Comment: @LSSJBroly I do not know whether the great poet Kalidasa and the author of Uttarakalamrita are the same person or not. I guess they are not the same person.

Comment: @LSSJBroly Mantreswara was an ardent follower of Parasar. He was a historical figure. A well-travelled man. You can read more about him in the English translation of the book "Mantreswara's Phaladeepika with an English Translation by Panditabhushana V. Subrahamanya Sastri, 2nd Edition, 1950"

Comment: @LSSJBroly In fact Mantreswar first introduced one of the very useful predictive techniques known as "Bhavatbhavam" that astrologers use regularly.

Comment: Ohh..I was unaware of that..That bhavatbhavam was introduced by mantreshawara. Thanks for letting me know :)